# Intellij - Move Caret to Next/Previous Word with Selection UNTIL SPACE?

Tags: intellij-idea, hotkeys, intellij-13

I'm trying to perform the action of the "Move Caret to Next/Previous Word with Selection", but not have it stop until it hits a space.  When I use the existing hotkey (without the space addition), I almost always find myself pressing it multiple times.  Thanks!

Comment: Are you looking for the 'Use "CamelHumps" words' option in Settings/Editor/General/Smart Keys? (It sounds like you may want to turn it off?) Or something else? Can you give some specific examples of text, where the cursor is, what key you want to hit, and what you want that key to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not currently possible, please vote for [IDEA-68325](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-68325) and linked tickets